# limit of multivariate function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have a function $y=(\sum_i(ln(X_i))^a)^{1/a}$, where $a$ is negative. I am wondering what the value of $\lim_{\textbf{X} \rightarrow\infty} y$, should be 0 or infinity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit is $+\infty$.

Set $X'=(x,\ldots,x)$, where $x=\min_iX_i$ with $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$. We have 
$$\lim_{X\rightarrow \mathbf{\infty}}y 
\ge \lim_{X'\rightarrow \mathbf{\infty}}(n\ln^ax)^{1/a}
=\lim_{X'\rightarrow \mathbf{\infty}}n^{1/a}\ln x=+\infty.$$